# What is the difference between int *p; and ClassA *Obj?

Tags: objective-c, c

Could anybody explain me the difference between the pointer concept when using primitive datatypes like int and Objective-C data types like NSString?

thanks,
bala

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are just that. They locate a memory location. You de-reference that pointer(location) to either primitive data type or user defined types as appropriate. I don't see a difference b/w pointers to user defined and primitive data types.

Comment: I can able to use NSString *myString = @"Hello"; its compiling fine, but int *p=50; is throwing errors. Both are pointer variables. Can you explain it little bit clear?

Comment: That's because @"Hello" is itself a pointer. The compiler creates an object somewhere in a location that you don't care about, and returns a pointer to that location. 50 is just the number, not a pointer to that number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both pointer had been initialised properly dereferencing the former gives you an `int`, whereas doing so to the latter gives you a `ClassA`.

So in fact there is no difference, but the data instance those pointers are referring to.

Comment: I can able to use NSString *myString = @"Hello"; its compiling fine, but int *p=50; is throwing errors. Both are pointer variables. Can you explain it little bit clear?

Comment: @Bala: Please see the *gnasher729*'s comment on *Prabhu*'s answer.